# Developing a plugin in Lighttpd

Tags: c++, plugins, webserver, lighttpd

I'm using the web server Lighttpd and I'm absolutely new to it. I managed to install and get in running in CentOS 6.2. I now want to make a plugin for lighttpd using Cpp, but I couldn't find any helpful tutorial at all and totally confused now. Could anybody help me with clear info?

Comment: What are you writing this plugin for?

Answer (score 2):

You won't be writing a plugin in C++, you'll be using straight C. There aren't any tutorials in the sense of building a Hello World application, but there is some documentation. http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki#Developing-Information is the place to start. Read the links there in order, especially http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/HowToWriteALighttpdPlugin and mod_skeleton.c in the lighttpd source.

Once you have those, the only thing to do is start experimenting!